# Use wmic to join domain and change computer name simultaneously

Tags: windows, cmd, active-directory

I'm trying to create a AD setup script, and I need to change the hostname then join the domain.

If I execute both of the following command, the domain will not be joined:

```
wmic computersystem where name='%computername%' call rename name='NEW_NAME'
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call joindomainorworkgroup fjoinoptions=3 name="XXX.com" username="XXX\admin" Password="XXXX"
```

It works only if I execute them one by one. But in explorer user can configure both properties simultaneously.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove *call* and try it that way,  I found a thread where someone said *call* was not needed, and that might be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

There's certain delay needed between the two executions, try these.

1. Rename-Computer -NewName "TheName"
2. sleep 10
3. add-computer -DomainName "dOmain.cOm" -Credential dOm\uSr -force -Options JoinWithNewName,AccountCreate -restart